# Bounded integral converges to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I consider some surfaces $N_t$ moving in time and a function $f$ such that

$\int_{N_t} f < \infty$ for all $t >0$.

Can I pick a subsequence $t_j$ such that $t_j \rightarrow \infty$ and

$\int_{N_{t_j}} f \rightarrow 0 $ ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always. Consider the sphere with radius $t$ around the origin and the function that measures the inverse of the square of the distance to the center. Then the integrals are constant and nonzero.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would it be true if we knew that $\int_{t_0}^{\infty}e^{t/2}\int_{N_t}f < \infty$ ? this gives us a stronger assumption right ?

Comment: That rather changes the game. It may depend on how you define the integrability condition and I suspect that it might yet fail for certain oscillatory integrals but if $f$ is positive and such a sequence of times as in your original question does not exist, then the last integral from your comment diverges.

Comment: OK, thanks! I just know that my function $f$ is positive.